# Making a proxy to block websites

Tags: c#, vb.net, proxy, localhost

I am making a proxy for Windows. I would like to be able to block certain documents under specific URLs.

For example, everything on google.com would work fine, but google.com/index.html could be blocked.

Can anyone help with this please?

I want the proxy to run on the same PC that uses it.

Comment: Please show us your existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what I needed. Sorry if I wasn't specific enough.

For any future users who come across this post and know what they are after - try FiddlerCore for .NET applications. It's a great package enabling you to capture and 'fiddle' with HTTP and HTTPS responses before they reach your device.

This means that FiddlerCore can be used to analyse a request's header, check for a certain URL and then drop the request.

Comment: `Sorry if I wasn't specific enough.` The main issue is that you said you were **making** a proxy. If you said you wanted to **use** a proxy then people would have suggested Fiddler.

Comment: No problem :) Sorry I wasn't clear enough with my post

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods:

(1) using FiddlerCore package
(2) modification of "hosts" file

1)
FiddlerCore is a .NET package which is used to analyse packets in the network.
A deep knowledge in FiddlerCore is required because it contains dangerous functions as well as most helpful functions.

2)
You can block websites by appending curresponding URL to the "hosts" file.
Navigate to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc, changing C: to whatever drive letter you have Windows installed on. Select "hosts" to open it.
Just append in a new line :
127.0.0.1

You want to get Administrative privilege for your application to modify the hosts file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this'll block the entire web server, as appose to just enabling my application to block only specific documents or files.

Comment: FiddlerCore package can be used instead of first method to block only specific documents or files.